# Allowing user to choose to display entire number in calculator or only 2 decimals

Tags: c#

I'm making a basic calculator and I'm wondering how I would go on to make the user choose if he/she wants to display the full result or only the result with 2 decimals. For example, if user puts in first number 4.213 and second number 4.6321, method "+" then the console asks "Do you wish to display the entire result or round it to 2 decimals" at which the user can type in "Yes" or "No".

I'm not looking for the program to round up the decimals, just display 2 decimals or the entire number.

I'm guessing if and else statement would be the way to go here.

Code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int runda;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

                List<double> Numbers = new List<double>();
                string Method = "";

            while (true)
            {

            loop:
                try
                {

                    Numbers.Add(ConvStr(TakeUserInput("First Number:")));
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Error, try again.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    goto loop;
                }
                Console.Clear();

            looop:
                try
                {

                    Numbers.Add(ConvStr(TakeUserInput("Second Number:")));
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Error, try again.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    goto looop;
                }
                Console.Clear();


                do
                {

                    Method = TakeUserInput("Choose method: ");

                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Error (Endast Addition (+) Subtraktion (-) Multiplikation (*) samt division (/)");
                }
                while (!CheckMethod(Method));

                    Console.Clear();

                  **HERE IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE USER TO CHOOSE IF DISPLAY ENTIRE NUMBER OR ONLY 2 DECIMALS**

                Console.WriteLine("Result:");
                Console.WriteLine(Calc(Numbers, Method));
                Console.WriteLine("If you wish to keep using this calculator press Enter.");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Numbers.Clear();
            }
        }


        private static string TakeUserInput(string DisplayText)
        {
            Console.Write(DisplayText);
            return Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static bool CheckMethod(string method)
        {
            switch(method)
            {
                case "+":
                    break;
                case "-":
                    break;
                case "*":
                    break;
                case "/":
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        private static double Calc(List<double> input, string method)
        {
            double Answer = 0;

            switch (method)
            {
                case "+":
                    Answer = input[0] + input[1];
                    break;
                case "-":
                    Answer = input[0] - input[1];
                    break;
                case "*":
                    Answer = input[0] * input[1];
                    break;
                case "/":
                    Answer = input[0] / input[1];
                    break;
            }


            return Answer;
        }

        private static double ConvStr(string input)
        {

            return Convert.ToDouble(input = input.Replace(".", ","));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Give it a try, sounds fine to me.

Comment: Not sure how I would do it. I just know that I would probably use if and else statements.

Comment: [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Answer (score -1):

Might be wrong but couldn’t you 
1). Turn the integer(result) into a string
2). Use the .indexOf(“”) function on the string to get the location of the period
3). check the index+3 to be in range of the result in order to not give any errors (3 to skip the period as well) 
4). Use the .remove(index) function to remove all other numbers at the new index
5). Use Convert.toInt32(string) to get its value back

Also there is a “Data.” something function which enables you to calculate the result of a string representation of the expression if that is of any help